# How do I group Contacts in a view on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently want to have a UI similar to SnapChat when it comes to displaying contacts.

[image: SnapChat contacts]

In other words, i want two sections in my scrollable view.

Which element is this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use two listviews, in a layout something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/layoutContainingTwoLists"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inContactsLayout"
        layout_width="match_parent"
        layout_height="0dp"
        layout_weight="1"
        >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inContactsText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SNAPCHATTERS IN MY CONTACTS"
                />

           <!--  YOU POPULATE THIS LISTVIEW WITH THE "SNAPCHATTERS IN CONTACTS" LIST -->
            <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/inContactsList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/inContactsText"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                >
            </ListView>
   </RelativeLayout>
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/notInContactsLayout"
        layout_width="match_parent"
        layout_height="0dp"
        layout_weight="1"
        >
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notInContactsText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="INVITE CONTACTS"
                />

           <!--  YOU POPULATE THIS LISTVIEW WITH THE "NOT IN CONTACTS" LIST -->
            <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/notInContactsList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/notInContactsText"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                >
            </ListView>

   </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you have considered this, but using an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) might be better for this situation. `ExpandableListView` allows you to specify `Views` for groups (i.e. headers of sections) and a different `View` for the children of a group.

Here is a [Github repo](https://github.com/emmano/FoodEssentials/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/foodessentials/widget/ProductDetailsExpandableListAdapter.java) where I implemented an `Adapter` for an `ExpandableListView` that you can use as reference.